# Using HMM or depmixS4 package to find log-likelihood values

Tags: r, likelihood, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization

I am trying to implement a Hidden Markov Model. In my studies we used the package HMM as well as wrote our own functions. Here is a slight modification of the example from the HMM package.

```
library(HMM)
hmm = initHMM(c("A","B"), c("L","R"), transProbs=matrix(c(.8,.2,.2,.8),2),
          emissionProbs=matrix(c(.6,.4,.4,.6),2))
observations = sample(c("L","R"),prob=c(.8,.2),size=100,replace=TRUE)

fit = baumWelch(hmm,observations)
```

Using the above code I have given all of the parameter values for the HMM - the state space, the observation space, the transition matrix, and the emission matrix. Once I have those I can use an observation sequence and the Baum Welch algorithm to optimize the parameters of the HMM.

So far so good. However in practice I would like to model a HMM with 3 states and I've read up on regime modeling, setting up a different HMM for each state and then taking the HMM with the highest log-likelihood for an observation sequence. (http://gekkoquant.com/2014/09/07/hidden-markov-models-examples-in-r-part-3-of-4/)

I don't see a way to grab the log likelihood values using the HMM package and I am completely lost as how to convert this simple example from the HMM package syntax to the depmixS4 syntax. Could anyone shed some light on how to do that? Or if not is it possible to calculate the log-likelihood values of each model for a given observation using the HMM package?

Also conceptually what is the distribution family of the example I've used? In the depmixS4 package one must specify a distribution. It seems like it would be a binomial distribution but I'm not sure. The syntax and setup of depmixS4 is challenging for me, despite great documentation.